# How do I get a field value from parent containers if the current content's same field is empty? Plone 4

Tags: plone, zope

I have added an attribute to all Folders using schema extension.  The new attribute is called greetingText.  Each folder can have greetingText throughout the chain A > B > C, however I have defaulted greetingText to empty string ('').  If B has a greetingText and the current context is for object B, then it should show B greetingText.  If folder B or C has empty string for its greetingText, then if object B is the current context, I want obj.getFields('greetingText') to give the container folder A's greetingText instead.  I understand that this is how Acquisition works, yet I think it only works this way if folder B's greetingText was None rather than an actual value, which is empty string.  This is from the context of a Controller Python Script connected to a Controller Page Template.

```
from Products.CMFPlone import PloneMessageFactory as _
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

plone_utils = getToolByName(context, 'plone_utils')
plone_log=context.plone_log

req = context.REQUEST
res = req.RESPONSE

greeting = context.getField('greetingText').getAccessor(context)()

msg = "id= %s"%(greeting)

res.write(msg)

return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aq_parent attribute of an object allows you to get at the parent. You can climb the object hierarchy looking for a greeting:

```
greeting = ''
while context is not None:
    accessor = getattr(context, 'getGreetingText')
    if accessor:
        greeting = accessor()
        if greeting:
            break
    context = context.aq_parent
```

This assumes you haven't changed the name of the Archetypes accessor for the field.

Comment: Great answer, and prompt to.  I did not clarify that for folder C in the scenario, it would first check folder B if it has no greetingText of its own, but if folder B had no greetingText, I would want it to go as far up as folder A.  Folder A's level will always have a non-empty value.  Your answer I believe will only work if the direct parent has a greetingText but not read further up the line of ancestors.  Am I correct?  If so, is there any way that you know of to produce the behavior that I want?  My apologies as I know that changes the question.

Comment: I tried to loop it, but that threw it into an infinite loop.
    parent = context.aq_parent

    while not greetingText:

        if parent:
            field = parent.getField('greetingText')

            if field:
                greetingText = field.getAccessor(context)()

        parent = context.aq_parent

Comment: I've rewritten to climb the object tree. Let me know if it doesn't work!